# Core Bluetooth: Transmit specific data in background as advertiser

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to use an iOS BLE device as BLE peripheral which also advertises in background.

I already figured out how to advertise in background and got it detected by another device looking for the specific bluetooth UUDID.

Unfortunately the advertiser-info is not transmitted when the app is in background. Is there a way to send a short string or something else device specific when the app is in background? It would be ok if the app would be woken up for a short period (if this is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advertised services are removed from the advertisement packages when the app is backgrounded. Only foreground scanning iOS devices will be able to obtain the services.

The advertised services are arbitrary UUIDs. You can easily figure out some encoding to store characters in them. However, this has several caveats, like

- the general scheme is usually that the scanner finds your peripheral by the service UUIDS. If the data can be anything, then this is tricky.
- the peripheral will not be able to change the advertisement data while backgrounded.

I suggest you not try to trick around with the system. Rather plan for connecting to the peripheral for a short time and sending the data to the central during this interval.

Comment: The thing is that the periphal is an iOS Device too. So basically I need to wake up both. The Sender and The Receiver. Is this possible?

Comment: No. If both apps are backgrounded, then scanning will not find the peripheral. Check out this answer for more details on backgrounded restrictions http://stackoverflow.com/a/21448538/768935